# in css, how to responsively stick element to certain background image part?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

and keep it in the same, as possible, position, relatively to the background image, while resizing (i.e. open in different devices) ?

For example, there is a background image of building, and on top of it, it is required to create a hover button that should be on the left top corner of it:

```
.bg 
{
    /* the background */
    background-image:       url(http://www.everbluetraining.com/sites/default/files/u47558/commercial-buildings.jpg);
    
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100%
   height:100%;
}

.mybtn 
{
   /* button image */
    background-image: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dc8/ok9/dc8ok9nMi.png);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

.mybtn:hover 
{
    opacity: 0.5;
}


<body class="bg">
    <div class="mybtn"></div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/saxzfoe2/

This looks nice in 720px width, but any changes to the screen size make this roll out of required position, where to dig ? maybe, some help of media queries should do the thing ?

(tried with % and em instead of px but still same stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to keep the button on the position's background you want to use the media query for 4 break point.

add this code on the css :

```
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
```

and edit the `background-size : cover` to `contain`.

```
.bg {
  position : relative; // important
  background-size : contain;
}
.myBtn{
   position : absolute;
}
```

after that use the media query , for example (it's a sample!) :

```
@media all and (min-width:720px) and (max-width: 767px){
  .myBtn{
      left : 10%;
      top  : 15%;
   } 
}
@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:960px){
  .myBtn{
     left : 20%;
     top  : 15%;
   }
}
```

find your Break  Point on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rule in your top on the css file.

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks! it is much better, but button still rolls out when i make screen wider, maybe some workaround exists for this issue ? maybe, it is possible to do media queries for this stuff ?